# Methods with classname as a return type

Tags: c#, methods

I'm new in c# or any type of programming language.
When I see codes in c# I found there are lot of confusions are over here. one of them I want to clarify from here.
Methods common structure is

```
<modifier><return type><method name>()
{
//do any thing
return <abc which should same as return type which declared above>;
}
```

in above said example I saw many times in `<return type>` use of `<class name>`, `<dictionary>` etc.
but natural these are also user defined types. so this also should be here. But, never stood what happened actually here when we use "class name" in place of string or any data type?

Please let me understand this with easy words, and easy examples.

```
class StockData
{
    public int StockID { get; set; };
    public double CurrentPrice { get; set; };
    public string StockName { get; set; };
}

class GetStock
{
    public StockData /*(this is the same name which is the class name above)*/ GetStockData(string symbol)
    {
        //something
        return /*(what will be the return type?)*/;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it? Can you clarify?

Comment: Please add specific code sample that is not clear for you.

Comment: Not sure if that's what you're asking, but I think your confusion is about how generics work. A method can only have one return type. `String` is one type. `List<string>` is another type entirely. `List<int>` is another type, and so on. So a generic type should not be marked again in the method definition because they already make **one type**.

Comment: Your method `public stockData getStockData(string Symbol)` is OK. You defined it to return `stockData`, so just return a `stockData` object. For example: `public stockData getStockData(string Symbol){ stockData thing = new stockData(); thing.stockName = Symbol; return thing; }`

Comment: no, this is not actually. I've modified my question. Might be it will be easy to get my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

In `GetStockData` method return type would be `StockData` i.e. you will have to return an instance of `StockData` class or any sub-class inherited from `StockData`. It depends on your code whether you create that instance in the `GetStockData` method or get from some other method, but surely type of the instance should be `StockData` or any sub-class inherited from `StockData` class.

Answer (score 1):

So if we have a **class** `Triangle` and a **method** `GetTriangle` which has the **parameter** `isBlue`.

```
public class Triangle
{
    public string Colour { get; set; }
}

public Triangle GetTriangle(bool isBlue)
{
    Triangle resultTriangle;

    if (isBlue)
    {
        resultTriangle = new Triangle { Colour = "Blue" };
    }
    else
    {
        resultTriangle = new Triangle { Colour = "Red" };
    }

    return resultTriangle;
}
```

We can call `GetTriangle` with an argument of `true` or `false` like so:

```
Triangle blueTriangle = GetTriangle(true);

Triangle redTriangle = GetTriangle(false);
```

Both of the results of `GetTriangle` are `Triangle`s, even though they contain different data (in this case a different `Colour`).

Like a child's wood-block toy, the compiler checks what the "shape" of the data is, not what colour it is. So if you try to return a `Square` from a method which returns `Triangle` then the compiler will throw an error in the same way you wouldn't be able to put a square block in a triangle hole.